# How can i get multiple data from multiple tags as store them as json in javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<select class="form-control js-example-basic-single getDress" name="dress[]" id="dress"
                                    style="width: 50%;">
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount[]" style="width: 40%;"
                                   placeholder="How many?">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="add-more"><i
                                        class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                            </div
```

> The html is above

```
 let dress = document.getElementsByName('dress[]');
    let amount = document.getElementsByName('amount[]');

        let a, b, i;
    for ( i = 0; i < dress.length && amount.length; i++) {
         a = dress[i];
        b = amount[i];
       
    let Dresses = [];
    Dresses[i] = [a.value, b.value];
    console.log(Dresses[i]);


    let k, n = Dresses.length;
    console.log(Dresses.length);

        let tmp = [];
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            tmp[k] = new DressDetails(Dresses[k][0], Dresses[k][1]);
            console.log(tmp[k]);
        }
        let objJSON = JSON.stringify(tmp);
        console.log(objJSON);
```

And is there any way to combine the JSON response together? As I am getting the response separately.

The response it's giving me is `[{"dressType":"T-Shirt","dressAmount":"2"}]`. Works only with 1 input. But if there are multiple inputs, It's showing me this error" `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`".

Comment: What do you expect `i < dress.length && amount.length` to do? Did you mean `i < dress.length && i < amount.length`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon. Yeah thats what i mean. But seems yours is more logical to follow.

Comment: The semantics are different. `i < dress.length && amount.length` means _“`i` is less than the `length` of `dress` and the `length` of `amount` is not `0`”_.

Comment: @SebastianSimon. Please explain further.

Comment: please provide clear code.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```js
let dress = [{
  value: 'dress1'
}, {
  value: 'dress2'
}]
let amount = [{
  value: 1
}, {
  value: 2
}]

const result = dress.map((dress, index) => ({
  dress: dress.value,
  price: amount[index].value
}))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes. Like this. I want to get multiple values from each of the variables from each tags

Comment: does this answer your question? if not, what is the expected output?

Comment: Its the expected output. But it does not give me the same output at my end

Comment: @bel2atar The html above is what is being duplicated to get the multiple json response

Answer (score 0):

```
let dress = document.getElementsByName('dress[]');
    let amount = document.getElementsByName('amount[]');
    let a, b, i;
    let Dresses = [];
    let tmp = [];
    for (i = 0; i < dress.length && i < amount.length; i++) {
        a = dress[i];
        b = amount[i];
        Dresses[i] = [a.value, b.value];
    }
    Dresses.forEach((Dresses, index) => {
        tmp[index] = new DressDetails(Dresses[0], Dresses[1]);
        // console.log( new DressDetails(Dresses[0], Dresses[1]));
        //  console.log('Index: ' + index + ' Value: ' + Dresses);

    });
    let objJSON = JSON.stringify(tmp);
    console.log(objJSON);
```

Finally got it right. This is the right format. Thanks for the help.